# The Typescript compiler making weird assumptions during comparisons

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class. But comparison logic is acting strangely.

```
class Lexer {
    currChar: string;

    nextChar(): void {
        this.currPos += 1;

        if (this.currPos >= this.code.length) {
            this.currChar = '\0';
        } else {
            this.currChar = this.code.charAt(this.currPos);
        }
    }

    skipComment(): void {
        if (this.currChar === "#") {
            while (this.currChar !== "\n") {
                this.nextChar();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result of running this (after instantiating this class) is

**error TS2367:** This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '"#"' and '"\n"' have no overlap.

I'm assuming the typescript compiler decides that because we checked that `this.currChar` was equal to '#', the while loop's condition should always be true. this.nextChar() changes the value of currChar though so it could result to false.

The weirder thing is that when this `skipComment` function is written like this
it works just fine.

```
skipComment(): void {
    if (this.currChar === "#") {
        this.currChar = '0';
        while (this.currChar !== "\n") {
            this.nextChar();
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the logic be that this.currChar is set to '0' so it should not equal "\n" just like in the first case which would be set to '#' because it even passed the if check.

Hope my question is not too vague.

Thanks.

Comment: For reference: [TypeScript GitHub Issue #9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) and [Issue #50839](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50839).